# What is known about the phase of matter at very high temperature and enough pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

Are there theoretical reasons for or against the existence of materials that will *not* become solid at some fixed, sufficiently large temperature when enough pressure is applied? Or is this even the normal state of affairs?

The usual phase diagrams typically only give a finite portion of the thermodynamical state space, probably as more cannot be experimentally tested.

But theory might tell us what happens, one way or another.

Comment: I do not know for sure obviously, but something tells me that nothing is harder to make solid than some good old Jovian hydrogen. I would speculate that if the temperature is high enough, adding too much pressure would only cause the atoms to slip and slide all over, possibly even making it a superviscous substance. But if you subscribe to the big bang theory, then you might believe that matter cannot be classified when that much pressure is applied, and temperature has lost all meaning.

Answer (score 1):

There is a point in which it is too hot for a molecule to remain bonded and will break apart, no matter how much pressure is applied. Now with more pressure the electrons and nuclei will start free flowing in what is known as a plasma. And add a little more heat and fission happens.

So basically the reason they don't show you any more of the curve because your molecule under enough pressure and heat is no longer a molecule.

Comment: Could you please give a reference for the unset of fission (at fixed very high temperature) if pressure is large enough? I have seen equations of state for aluminum including gas and plasma phases. How would an aluminum atom decay under high pressure?

Comment: Its hard to say when fission does happen but a good reference could be the earths core, were fission happens with heavy elements, with a pressure of a few GPa and about 5000degrees Celsius. To correct myself, yes all material will become a solid with enough pressure, pressure which is only possible in celestial body's. Molecules do not retain their chemical and physical properties at such temperatures and act as a plasma.

Comment: How would an aluminum atom decay under high pressure? - How can a material be both solid and plasma, as your comment suggests? - I'd appreciate if you'd add references to your answer, so that I can judge for myself.